# Unable to invoke a lambda from another lambda using aws serverless offline

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless, aws-serverless, serverless-offline

I want to invoke a lambda from another lambda inside serverless-offline .I want to make a serverless offline web application.But I am getting this error:

> { UnknownError: Unsupported Media Type
>       at Object.extractError (C:\Users\gourabkonar\Desktop\sls-demo\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\protocol\json.js:51:27)
>       at Request.extractError (C:\Users\gourabkonar\Desktop\sls-demo\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\protocol\rest_json.js:55:8)
>       at Request.callListeners (C:\Users\gourabkonar\Desktop\sls-demo\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\sequential_executor.js:106:20)
>       at Request.emit (C:\Users\gourabkonar\Desktop\sls-demo\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\sequential_executor.js:78:10)
>       at Request.emit (C:\Users\gourabkonar\Desktop\sls-demo\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\request.js:683:14)
>       at Request.transition (C:\Users\gourabkonar\Desktop\sls-demo\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\request.js:22:10)
>       at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (C:\Users\gourabkonar\Desktop\sls-demo\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\state_machine.js:14:12)
>       at C:\Users\gourabkonar\Desktop\sls-demo\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\state_machine.js:26:10
>       at Request. (C:\Users\gourabkonar\Desktop\sls-demo\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\request.js:38:9)
>       at Request. (C:\Users\gourabkonar\Desktop\sls-demo\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\request.js:685:12)
>       at Request.callListeners (C:\Users\gourabkonar\Desktop\sls-demo\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\sequential_executor.js:116:18)
>       at Request.emit (C:\Users\gourabkonar\Desktop\sls-demo\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\sequential_executor.js:78:10)
>       at Request.emit (C:\Users\gourabkonar\Desktop\sls-demo\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\request.js:683:14)
>       at Request.transition (C:\Users\gourabkonar\Desktop\sls-demo\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\request.js:22:10)
>       at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (C:\Users\gourabkonar\Desktop\sls-demo\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\state_machine.js:14:12)
>       at C:\Users\gourabkonar\Desktop\sls-demo\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\state_machine.js:26:10
>       at Request. (C:\Users\gourabkonar\Desktop\sls-demo\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\request.js:38:9)
>       at Request. (C:\Users\gourabkonar\Desktop\sls-demo\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\request.js:685:12)
>       at Request.callListeners (C:\Users\gourabkonar\Desktop\sls-demo\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\sequential_executor.js:116:18)
>       at callNextListener (C:\Users\gourabkonar\Desktop\sls-demo\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\sequential_executor.js:96:12)
>       at IncomingMessage.onEnd (C:\Users\gourabkonar\Desktop\sls-demo\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\event_listeners.js:307:13)
>       at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:203:15)
>       at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:448:20)
>       at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1129:12)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
>     message: 'Unsupported Media Type',
>     code: 'UnknownError',
>     time: 2019-11-06T17:02:27.641Z,
>     requestId: undefined,
>     statusCode: 415,
>     retryable: false,
>     retryDelay: 6.643720301281952 }

---

**sls-api-dev-create**

```
   const jobs=[
    { id: 1,title: 'NodeJS Developer'},
    {id: 2, title:'Angular Developer'}
];


var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.region = 'ap-southeast-2';

let lambda = new AWS.Lambda({
    region: 'ap-south-1',
    endpoint: 'http://localhost:3000/jobs'
})
module.exports.handler=async(evt,ctx)=>{

    console.log(evt.body);
    jobs.push(JSON.parse(evt.body));

    lambda.invoke({
        FunctionName: 'sls-api-dev-hello',
        InvocationType: 'Event',
        Payload:null    
    },function(err,data){
        console.log('No error');
        if(!err)
        console.log(data);
        else
        console.log(err);

    })
    //console.log(response);
    return {
        statusCode :200,
        body:JSON.stringify({
            jobs
        })
    }
}
```

**sls-api-dev-hello**

```
'use strict';

module.exports.hello = async event => {
  return {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify(
      {
        message: 'Welcome to Serverless',
        input: event,
      },
      null,
      2
    ),
  };

  // Use this code if you don't use the http event with the LAMBDA-PROXY integration
  // return { message: 'Go Serverless v1.0! Your function executed successfully!', event };
};
```

**serverless.yml**

```
service: sls-api



provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs10.x
  region: ap-south-1
  iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: Allow
      Action:
        - lambda: InvokeFunction
        - lambda: InvokeAysnc
      Resource: "*"

plugins:
  - serverless-offline
  - serverless-offline-lambda

functions:
  hello:
    handler: handler.hello
  jobs:
    handler: src/jobs/handler.handler
  listJobs:
    handler: src/jobs/list.handler
    events:
      - http:
          method: GET
          path: /jobs
  createJobs:
    handler: src/jobs/create.handler
    environment:
      SOME_VARIABLE: http://localhost:3000/jobs
    events:
      - http:
          method: POST
          path: /jobs
  getJob:
    handler: src/jobs/findOne.handler
    events:
      - http:
          method: GET
          path: /jobs/{id}
          request:
            parameters:
              id: true
```

Please help ,Any help would be great as I am new to serverless.Thanks in advance.

Comment: See https://github.com/dherault/serverless-offline/issues/747

Comment: but its unsolved and tells that u need to used serverless-offline-lambda plugin.which i also tried but nothing good happened

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only thing you should change here is **endpoint** in your lambda instance configuration to point to base *serverless-offline* url. 
Also you do not need to use *serverless-offline-lambda* pluing at all.

Change Lambda options to something like this:

```
const lambda = new AWS.Lambda({
  region: "ap-south-1",
  endpoint: process.env.IS_OFFLINE ? "http://localhost:3000" : "https://lambda.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com",
});
```

Additionally, what this means

> process.env.IS_OFFLINE

? 
Means you are running lambda locally using *serverless-offline* plugin which actually sets this env variable.

Comment: I'm almost three years late, but for those who still runs into "Unsupported Media Type", I asked the question and answered it later at https://stackoverflow.com/a/73740260/1481519. The port in `http://localhost:3000` should be the port used in `--lambdaPort` CLI option. The default is `3002`. CLI options: https://www.serverless.com/plugins/serverless-offline#usage-and-command-line-options